# How to link same-directory CSS file and HTML file?

Tags: html, css, github

I am trying to figure out how to link my `style.css` file on my `index.html`.

The `style.css` file is in the ***same folder*** as my `index.html` file and this is how I'm trying to reference my css file as follows but it's not working:

```
<link href="aplusryan.github.io/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `style.css` file is in the same folder as your `index.html`, just use `./` instead of the full url to reference your stylesheet like this:

```
<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

> The dot-slash `"./"` is a relative path to something in the current
>   directory. The dot is the current directory and the slash is a path
>   delimiter.
>
> Via - [What does the ./ mean (dot slash) in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux)

Comment: Btw if the file is in the same folder, do we need to put the ./ mark? Why don't we just write just  " href="style.css"... "

Answer (score -1):

If your index and style sheet are in the same folder then the link should just be "style.css" you don't need the GitHub part.

If you put your stylesheet in a folder called css, and the CSS folder is the same level as index.html then you would link with "css/style.css"